# can not get the type of the function just right

Tags: string, haskell, types

I am trying to write a function which take a string and returns the original strings without the space character as a list of string e.g.
toStrings "thanks for your help" -> ["thanks", "for", "your", "help"].

I want to solve this problem using an accumulator so I did the following:

```
toStrings :: String -> [String]
toStrings str = go str [] 
 where 
  go str acc
   | str == [] = acc
   | otherwise = go (dropWhile (/=' ') str) acc : (takeWhile (/=' ') str)
```

It does not work. The compiler says:

```
Couldn't match type '[Char]' with 'Char'
```

I thought I was working with Strings. 
Help is much appreciated.

Thanks Eitan

Comment: A string is a `[Char]` (a list of `Char`s).

Comment: Unrelated: I'd recommend to avoid `==[]` tests in favor of pattern matching. I.e. `go [] acc = all ; go str acc = ...` is more idiomatic.

Comment: N.B. this is just the stdlib `words` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`takeWhile` on a `String` will return a `String`. Therefore, you have

```
go (…) acc : takeWhile (…)
```

where the latter is a `String`. However, you need `[String]` at that point. Since `String = [Char]`, we have the following type mismatch:

```
 String  =  [Char]  -- actual
[String] = [[Char]] -- expected
```

GHC then sees the `[[Char]]` and `[Char]`, removes one list layer, and sees `[Char]` and `Char`, which cannot get simplified anymore.

That's why you get your error. Type synonyms and simplified types in error messages.

That being said, you never change the `acc`, nor do you drop the spaces afterwards. Your current implementation will therefore loop infinitely.

I suggest you to solve this problem without an accumulator and instead try to come up with something similar to

```
-- pseudo code
go str = firstWord str : go (restOfString str)
```

Keep in mind that `firstWord` should strip leading spaces, or you end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Those were some very helpful insights.

Answer (score 5):

I think it helps if you add the type to the `go` function. Based on the function description it should be:

```
toStrings :: String -> [String]
toStrings str = go str [] 
 where 
  go str acc :: String -> [String] -> [String]
   | str == [] = acc
   | otherwise = go (dropWhile (/=' ') str) acc : (takeWhile (/=' ') str)
```

But in your recursive call, you call `(go somestr acc) : someotherstr` (I here use `somestr` and `someotherstr` to make it easier to see why it does not work). That does not match, since `go somestr acc` will result in a `[String]` (given that works), and `someotherstr` is a `String`. If you use the cons `(:)` it expects the head (left operand) to be a `String`, and the tail (right operand) to be a `[String]`.

But in fact here we do not need to work with an accumulator at all. We can construct a "cons" and perform recursion at the tail, like:

```
toStrings :: String -> [String]
toStrings ss | null s1 = []
             | otherwise = word : toStrings rest
    where s1 = dropWhile (== ' ') ss
          (word, rest) = span (/= ' ') s1
```

So first we drop all the spaces of the string `ss`, which is then `s1`. In case  `s1` is the empty list, then we are done, and we return the empty list. Otherwise we perform a `span` (a conditional split) such that we obtain a tuple with the word as the first item, and the rest of the string as second item. We then yield the `word`, and perform recursion on the `rest`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Writing the type of go has really helped me to see part of my problem. I do understand that I do not necessarily need to use an accumulator. Just for practice sake I would like to complete my problem using an accumulator.  I see I used the cons operator wrong. It needs to be:  (takeWhile (/= ' ') str) : acc.  It compiles now ... but I get an endless recursion. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @eitan: yeah, I mixed p `span` and `break` :S.